# Is it possible to bind a buffer for both transform feedback and rendering?

Tags: opengl, transform-feedback

I read a tutorial on transform feedback which did something like this:

```
create Buffer1 with data
create Buffer2 for transform feedback

RenderLoop (ith loop):
Bind buffer1 for rendering
bind buffer2 for transform feedback
Render

RenderLoop (i+1th loop):
Bind buffer2 for rendering
Bind buffer1 for transform feedback
Render
```

My question is, is it possible to use only one buffer for achieving the above?

Comment: It's possible, but not all that is possible makes sense or gives well-defined results. Reading from and writing to the same buffer will almost certainly give only garbage.

Comment: ofcourse, by "is it possible" i meant it being technically correct giving correct logical results.

Comment: Well, you can read and write to the same buffer using atomic operations and get well-defined results, but neither using transform feedback nor textures/framebuffers will give predictable results when reading from and writing to the same resource. Think about what happens when you do what you want. As soon as TF starts, the buffer's contents are explicitly undefined, and even if it's factually still valid, it is being overwritten while you read vertex attributes from it, and not even necessarily at the same rate. What predictable result _could_ possibly come out of that?